# My subclass can't heritate properly from parent class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class named "Product" that heritates from a base class named "Command" . Every time I execute the function1 as shown below by calling an attribute from the base class "L_R" it shows " NameError:name 'L_R' is not defined "

```
class Command:
   def__init__(self ,L_R,L_A,L_M):
    self.L_R=L_R
    self.L_M=L_M
    self.L_A=L_A
    ######
class Produit(Command): 
     def __init__(self, reference,position):
        super().__init__(self,L_R,L_A,L_M)
        self.reference=reference
        self.position=position

     def function1(self)
        ###
        if (self.L_R==condition):
            #some code
```

I think something is wrong with the super() but i can't find it

Comment: `Prodiut` is only being passed "reference" and "position" in it's init method. Where are these arguments coming from?

Comment: these are the attributes of the class Product. it's a child class that heritates some attr/functions but has its own attr/functions also

Comment: You haven't set these attributes? If they are class attributes they should not be passed in to the init

Comment: yes they are product attributes. sorry it sounds stupid but should i remove the whole __init__ method of the class product?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your super is a bit incorrect based on your code above. I am not going to try to interpret your `class`, just tell you how to fix your super to inherit your L_R, L_A, L_M arguments. If you want Produit to inherit them specifically each time it is instantiated you need to pass them to the `__init__` of the `super()`:

```
class Command:
   def__init__(self ,L_R,L_A,L_M):
    self.L_R=L_R
    self.L_M=L_M
    self.L_A=L_A
    ######
class Produit(Command): 
     def __init__(self, L_R, L_A, L_M, reference, position):
        super().__init__(L_R,L_A,L_M)
        self.reference=reference
        self.position=position

     def function1(self)
        ###
        if (self.L_R==condition):
            #some code
```

If you want `Produit` to inherit whatever you have created from command you can do something like the following:

```
my_cmd_obj = Command(L_R, L_A, L_M)
my_prd_obj = Produit(my_cmd_obj, reference, position)
```

Where `L_R, L_A, L_M, reference, position` are variables in the actual program that should be arguments to the classes.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification But i think i'll have to call all these 5 attributes ( L_R, L_A, L_M, reference, position) every time i create an instance of the class Produit

Comment: If you create a `Command` class and then want `Produit` to inherit the class object you would call it like this:
`my_obj = Produit(Command(L_R, L_A, L_M), reference, position)` make sense?

Comment: actually it shows :
TypeError: __init__() missing  required positional arguments I'm really confused and i appreciate your help

Comment: If reference and position are generated from Command you need to pass them in the first init.